# Render default image in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using `url_for` to generate my images url.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/' + images[id]) }}" >
```

How to make `url_for` return `/static/imgs/default.jpg` when the requested image does not exist on the server ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: HTML / JavaScript

You can use `onerror` attribute:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imgs/' + images[id]) }}" onerror="this.src='/static/imgs/default.jpg'">
```

Or listen `error` event for `img` element with JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('img').on("error", function() {
  $(this).attr('src', '/static/imgs/default.jpg');
});
```

### Solution 2: Flask

If you just want make it with Flask, you will need to create a custom view function to handle your images, for example (not test yet):

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory

# ...

@app.route('/img/<path:filename>')
def get_image(filename):
    static_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static')
    img_path = os.path.join(static_path, filename)

    if not os.path.exists(img_path):
        return send_from_directory(os.path.join(static_path, '/imgs/default.jpg'))
    return send_from_directory(img_path)
```

Template code:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('get_image', filename='/static/imgs/' + images[id]) }}" >
```

### Solution 3: Nginx

In production, you may use web server like Nginx to serve images, in this case, you can use `[try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)` directive in Nginx:

```
location /static/imgs/ {
    try_files $uri /static/imgs/default.jpg;
}
```